# IBM i - DDS used for both display files and physical files

Tags: ibm-midrange

I was discussing IBM i DDS (Data Description language) with colleague and he seemed a bit surprised that the same language is used to define both display files and physical/logical files (tables). Although both describe single records and streams of data (think DDS display subfiles), it seems an unusual combination, and we could think of no other language that took this approach. Where did this approach come from and do any other languages use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, on the AS/400, all IO was record based. There were no stream based files. Incidentally database files, and device files are all record based. And with the exception of physical files, all support multiple record formats. Even communications files were record based. Since all these file types were processed in a common way, it stands to reason that they all are defined by a single language. Stream files are a later development, and are supported by a C language API rather than DDS. And like other computing environment, stream files are application described rather than externally defined the way "native" files are.

Interestingly, no files need be externally defined. They can be program described, and printer files are still frequently defined thus. In this case the files are described in the language that is using them (RPG or COBOL).

Answer (score 0):

DSPF PF LF are the off spring of punch card technology.